# Create C# dll and use method with powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, dll

I created a simple C# dll and registered it using `RegAsm.exe`. One very simple method is invoked without parameters and returns a number, here is a simplified version.

```
namespace AVL_test {
    interface ITestClass {
        int GetNumber();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class TestClass: ITestClass {
        public TestClass() { }

        public int GetNumber() {
            return 10;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to invoke that method from Powershell, so I added the type

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\myPath\AVL_test.dll"
```

It seems to be loaded because if I `[AVL_test.TestClass]` I get this output

> IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
>   -------- -------- ----                                     --------
>   True     False    TestClass                                System.Object

But if I try to invoke `GetNumber()` by typing`[AVL_test.TestClass]::GetNumber()` I get this error

> Method invocation failed because [AVL_test.TestClass] does not contain a method named 'GetNumber'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your method should be `static` or you need to create an instance of that type (TestClass).

Last can be done using

```
New-Object -TypeName <full qualified type name> -ArgumentList <args>
```

Or in your specific case:

```
$test = New-Object -TypeName AVL_Test.TestClass
$test.GetNumber()
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement a static method if I specify the interface? If I try to change method to `public static int GetNumber()` I get an error saying `'AVL_test.TestClass.GetNumber()' cannot implement an interface member because it is static`

Comment: No, if there is an interface as in your example, than the method cannot be declared to be static ...

Comment: On a related note, I don't think the `[ComVisible]` attribute is required for PowerShell interaction. You should only need this if you are registering the assembly as a COM object, but PowerShell will load .NET types and assemblies natively.

Comment: For the interaface question: You could add a static method, that is called by the interface method - just to provide both scenarios ...

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to get the same return value using PowerShell Binary Module? Ie. one that contains/inherits from cmdlet classes.