# powershell invoking c# DLL with Task Parallel library vs console exe with Task Parallel library

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll, task-parallel-library

I am [refering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097002/create-c-sharp-dll-and-use-method-with-powershell) this link for invoking a DLL from powershell

If the DLL method has TPL code, whether this will achieve true parallelism as opposed to TPL code in a console exe.

Can some one tell me the pros/cons of both approaches

Comment: I don't understand the question or what "true parallelism" is. Maybe providing an example would help?

Comment: My query here is we dont have an appdomain (out of process - DLL). if we  invoke via Task.Factory.StartNew, inside a DLL method started by powershell, will we have same treatment?