# How do I control a Beckhoff EtherCAT Coupler with powershell?

Tags: powershell, modbus

We have a Beckhoff EtherCAT Coupler which is currently being controlled by some c# code, we call that c# code from a powershell script. We want to move the entire process of toggling slots on the coupler to the powershell script but I'm not sure how to do that. If you could provide me even with information on how to send/receive Modbus commands in powershell that would be hugely helpful.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Here is the code used in C# to toggle one slot of the IO coupler:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Modbus.Device;

TcpClient tcp_connection = new TcpClient(ip, MODBUS_TCP_PORT);
ModbusIpMaster coupler = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(tcp_connection);

coupler.WriteSingleRegister(0x1120, 0);
coupler.WriteSingleCoil(slot, state);
```

Comment: This is a highly complex question with very little information provided. Do you have examples of your C# code? Does it have a GUI? Have you tried anything in PowerShell already? If so, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I've googled it to the best of my ability and haven't been able to find anything on what to do in powershell, and yea I'll add snippits of the code to the question, should've done that originally.

Comment: If it uses the .NET object model then you can usually port code to PowerShell. Hopefully someone here can point you in the right direction once some of the C# code is added.

Answer (score 1):

Acontis offers an EtherCAT Master for Windows library and a C# example application you could leverage to include into your own application: https://acontis.com/en/ecsta.html

Answer (score 0):

Working with machine automation controllers is highly manufacturer specific. I've got working knowledge only about Omron PLC & MACs, so I cannot provide exact details.

Anyway, one way would be to create a C# DLL and [call it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30097002/503046) from Powershell. As how to program the coupler, start by finding out which model, exactly, you are working with and searching Beckhoff's [documentation](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcsample_net/html/tcsample_net_intro.htm&id=). Maybe there are suitable samples available.

Consider also contacting manufacturer's support. They might be able to provide advice with very reasonable pricing, unless the task grows into a consulting gig.

Programming PLCs and MACs is often done via manufacturer specific solutions. Those are much simpler to use than general-purpose language such as C#.