# Can't execute non static method from DLL using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, class-library

I'm currently trying to execute methods from a C# Class library .dll with a powershell script.

This is the one and only class of my library:

```
namespace DLLCalculator
{
public class Calculator
{

    public static void addNumbers(int num1, int num2)
    {

        MessageBox.Show((num1 + num2).ToString());

    }



    public void helloWorld()
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");

    }


    }
}
```

This is the code of my powershell:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\DLLCalculator\DLLCalculator\bin\Debug\DLLCalculator.dll")
[DLLCalculator.Calculator]::addNumbers(10,5)
$Object = new-object DLLCalculator.Calculator
$Object.helloWorld()
```

This part of the powershell script here works perfectly fine and I get a messagebox with the desired result:

```
[DLLCalculator.Calculator]::addNumbers(10,5)
```

This here however does not work for some reason:

```
$Object = new-object DLLCalculator.Calculator
$Object.helloWorld()
```

How I see it it should work considering that the powershell script creates an object in order to execute the non static method.

I have also tried the command using the expression "-TypeName" from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30097144/13224253) but unfortunately it did not work either.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Method invocation failed because [DLLCalculator.Calculator] does not contain a method named 'helloWorld'.
At C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\PowershellStarter\PowershellStarter\bin\Debug\test.ps1:4 char:1
+ $Object.helloWorld()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

As seen above the function DOES exist but for some reason the powershell can't seem to find it for some odd reason.
What could be causing the problem?

Comment: @iRon Which "static property"? And: your link is broken.

Comment: @iRon unfortunattely the link does not work.

Comment: @iRon I am kind of confused by your question and think that you might have misinterpreted my question. My class is not written in powershell but in C#. That class exists within a class library (.dll file)

My goal is now calling the static and non static method from the .DLL file (which is writen in C#) with the powershell console.

Comment: Works for me when using `Add-Type`, I haven't tried with a whole assembly. Perhaps it's loading the wrong version of the library, perhaps a previous version was already loaded

Comment: @Charlieface This was it. I was loading the debug version but my IDE was compiling the release version. lol

The code is actually correct and works fine if the path is correct